# VBA Dynamically add option button to userform

Tags: vba, radio-button

I have this code to add an option button to a user form from https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/excel-userform/optionbutton/ which seems simple enough, but it gets an error "Type mis-match".

The userform has been added from Insert>UserForm in the editor.  The editor only gives one possible option in the statement "Dim OpBtn as OptionButton". So what could go wrong?

```
    Sub Add_Dynamic_OptionButton()

    Dim OpBtn As OptionButton

        'Add Dynamic OptionButton and assign it to object 'OpBtn'
        Set OpBtn = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1")  
             'ERRORS HERE

        'Assign OptionButton Name
        OpBtn.Caption = "Dynamic OptionButton"

        'OptionButton Position
        OpBtn.Left = 486
        OpBtn.Top = 48

    End Sub
```

I'd like to use this code to add an option button.  Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to qualify your reference `Dim OpBtn As msforms.OptionButton`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bring up the *Project References* dialog (from the *Tools* menu), you'll see the *Microsoft Excel* type library listed before the *MSForms* type library - and the sorting order is important.

When a data type isn't qualified with the library it's from, VBA uses the reference priority (i.e. the sort order) to determine who wins when two or more libraries define different types that have the same name. `Excel.OptionButton` is a thing, as is `MSForms.OptionButton` - but since the `Excel` library has higher priority (and can't be moved down since it's your host application), then `OptionButton` will bind to `Excel.OptionButton`.

But `UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1")` yields a `MSForms.OptionButton` - hence the *type mismatch*.

Fully qualify your data types, and the problem will solve itself.

```
Dim OpBtn As MSForms.OptionButton
```

Comment: Great explanation.  The code is in a module, not in the code behind the form. I made the change, but it still does not work for me.  The code does run. If it is creating a button, I don't know where it is going.  UserForm1 is a form in the same file as the module with the code.  There are no other open files. I added OpBtn.Visible = "true", without success.

Comment: "If it is creating a button, I don't know where it is going" is a strong hint that you're working with a default instance of the form. Does any thing unload it? Read the article I linked above: you want to consistently work off a `New` instance.

Comment: @Chas ...and add the buttons on every new instance of the form.

Comment: Got it working on new instance as suggested. Thanks.